# camera capture in actionscrip3

Tags: flash, actionscript, camera

I want to implement video chat with flash on client side and my custom server (python) on server side. I am newbie in flash and actionscript 3. I want simply to collect frames and send them to server. I read some documentation of actionscript and want to implement this in this way:

I want to control data structure, collect frames by timer and store them in ByteArray, than send this to server and resend to chat partner.

then on timer tick i can snapshot images and collect them:

```
    var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera(); 
    var vid:Video = new Video();
    vid.attachCamera(cam);
    private var fpsFrame:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

    //on timer event
    ...
    imgBD = new BitmapData(vid.width,vid.height); 
    imgBD.draw(vid);
    imgBitmap=new Bitmap(imgBD);

    imgBA = imgBitmap.bitmapData.getPixels(rect1)        

    //fpsFrame.writeObject(imgBD);
    //append frame
    fpsFrame.writeBytes(imgBA)
    imgBA.clear();

    //than i can add sound here and send to server
    ...
```

Is it good aproach to do this? what structures better to use for implementation?

Comment: No, I would say that it is not a good approach. I don't think capturing bitmap data and sending audio separately will make a successful video chat, especially when there are other readymade mechanisms in Flash/ActionScript for sending video to a streaming server.

Comment: why separately? i can send it with video in one frame, as i understand readymate stream restrict my server to some flash formats, i want implement it at all with my data format and search for better tool for this.

Comment: If you must, send only the modified bits (not the entire bitmap). e.g. the user's face changes, but the background mostly remains static (except moving curtains, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that if there are many options available on the market? FMS, Wowza, Red5 — these media servers are capable to set up your video chat in a matter of minutes. The whole Flash media infrastructure works around a media server: Camera, Video, NetStream. Data is encoded, sent, saved, loaded and decoded for you automatically.

And you want to manually draw screengrabs into bitmaps, compress them (there are png, jpeg even flv encoders in AS3), grab sound chunks, compress them too, send data to the other party, decode manually all the stuff and put it all together? I bet you will run into performance, network traffic and synchronization issues.

If you need a working solution right now use a media server. If you are a hacker and HAVE to know if it is possible or not you should try and do it (8 Make a library which does just that without a media server and post it to GitHub. That would be cool.

Comment: I want to do it for practice and exp., also i think i can simple add some custom features if i control all data format,than use in box solutions.